# Finding the largest aggregation of points in a circle with a radius r.

Tags: circles

I have multiple points on a map each with their own latitude and longitude.
Each point has a value associated to it.
Given a radius $r$, I want to find the centre of the circle with radius r that encompasses the largest aggregation of point values possible.

I need to make this scalable so it would need to work for hundreds of thousands of points.

Any ideas on how to get started on this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Random thought - could you treat each point as having the same mass and then find the centre of mass of all the points - I wonder if that would be where the centre of the circle should be?

Comment: Another random thought - start with a square of side length $r$ instead of a circle as maybe finding where such a square should lie would be a much easier problem to solve. Then maybe the circle should lie somewhere within that square?

Comment: In my last comment I meant to say "Then maybe the centre of the circle should lie somewhere within that square?"

Comment: I thought about finding the centre of mass and I think that is a good starting point. Why would you treat them all equally though? I think you would want them to be treated normally so the centre would be weighted towards the higher values?

Comment: I would consider each point as having the same mass and then find the centre of mass. After more thought on this I do not think it will give the correct answer. Consider the case where all points lie on the circumference of a circle with a radius larger than $r$. The centre of mass will be at the centre of that circle and all the points will be excluded. Maybe solving the square with side length $r$ might be more fruitful?